# Django - ModelForm display the item but insert the foreignkey

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have two models as ProjectContacts and the User:

```
class ProjectContacts(models.Model):
    project_contact_fname = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    project_contact_lname = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False)
    project_contact_group = models.ForeignKey(ProjectGroup)
    project_contact_title = models.ForeignKey(ProjectContactTitles)
    project_site_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    project_contact_add_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    project_contact_defined_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

In my form I am presenting the project_contact_defined_by field in the form as a read-only TextInput() in the form.py so that I can show the full name of the currently logged-in user in the form as readonly. However, in my view I have to set the initial field in order to show the full name. Below is my view.py

```
def add_project_contact(request):

    ..............

    form = ProjectContactForm(initial={'project_contact_defined_by' : request.user.get_full_name(),

    }, )

    return render(request,'members/rfc/create.html',{'form': form})
```

Now, I am having and issue with the record insertion here and I think when the form data gets inserted it is the full name that gets inserted not the user.id? I would appreciate it if someone can help me out here to resolve this.

Comment: Try: `'project_contact_defined_by' : request.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than displaying the user as read only form field, it would probably be better to exclude the field from your form, and display the user's name in the template, wherever you wish, as follows: `{{ request.user.get_full_name }}`

Then, after you check that the form is valid, you would set the User as follows:

```
project_contact = form.save(commit=False)  # This initializes the object with form data without saving, so you can edit or alter fields before the model is created
project_contact.project_contact_defined_by = request.user
project_contact.save()
```

You would also want to check that the user exists (and is not anonymous):

```
if user.is_authenticated():
    # Check that form is valid, then create model
```

Note that if you are using a generic FormView, then you will be overriding `form_valid()` (which already checks that the form is valid) and use self.request.user to access the user.